# Issue when iterating through lists: IndexOutOfBoundsException in Java

Tags: java, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a program that applies many principles of computational linguistics. My problem at this moment is the following piece of code form a method that "flexibilizes two definitions". This is, it compares two different definitions of the same word, and in each definition empty or blank spaces will be added to later on work with the altered definitions (with blank spaces added).
Say we have the following two definitions, defining the term "free fall".

```
1) Free fall descent  of a body subjected only to            the   action of  gravity.
2) Free fall movement of a body in        a    gravitational field under  the influence of gravity
```

There is a list of words called stoplist, which contains the words: "of", "a", "in", "to", and "under". After the process, each word in the definition that is also contained in the stoplist must correspond to a blank space OR another stoplist word of the other definition. So after executing such process, the previous definitions, represented in two different lists, should look like this:

```
1) Free fall descent  of a body ____ ____ subjected     only  to     the action    of gravity.
2) Free fall movement of a body in   a    gravitational field under  the influence of gravity.
```

The code I wrote to achieve this is the following:

```
[...]

String[] sList = STOPLIST.split(" ");  //this is the stoplist
String[] definition1 = defA1.split(" ");  //this is the array of words of the first definition
String[] definition2 = defA2.split(" ");  //this is the array of words of the second definition
List<String> def1 = new ArrayList<String>();  
List<String> def2 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> stopList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String word : definition1){
    def1.add(word); //I transform arrays into lists this way because I used to think that using .asList() was the problem.
}
for(String word : definition2){
    def2.add(word);
}
for(String word : sList){
    stopList.add(word);
}

int mdef = (def1.size() <= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size(); //here mdef will have the value of the lenght of the shortest definition, and we are going to use the value of mdef to iterate later on.

for(int i = 0; i < mdef; i++){
   if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) {  //here I check if the first word of the first definition is also found in the stoplist.
        if (!stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {  //If the word of def1 previously checked is in the stoplist, as well as the corresponding word in the second definition, then we won't add a " "(blank) space in the corresponding position of the second definition.
           def2.add(i , " "); //here I add that blank space, only if the stoplist word in def1 corresponds to a non-stoplist word in def2. Again, we do this so the stoplist word in def1 corresponds to a blank space OR another stoplist word in def2.
           if(mdef == def2.size())
               mdef++; //In case the shortest definition is the definition to which we just added spaces, we increment mdef++, because that space added increases the length of the shortest definition, and to iterate in this recenlty extended definiton, we have to increment the index with which we iterate.
        }
    } else if (stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) { //this else if does the same than the previous one, but checks for the second definition instead of the first one. And adds blanks to def1 instead of def2 if necessary.
        if (!stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) {
            def1.add(i , " ");
            if(mdef == def1.size())
                mdef++;
        }
    }
}

[...]
```

Now, if you analyze the code carefully, you will realize that not all words of the lengthiest list will be checked, given that we iterate ove the definitions using the lenght of the shortest definition as index. This is fine, the remainding words of the lenghtiest definitions don't have to be checked, they will correspond to null spaces of the other definition (in case the lists don't end up being of the same lenght after the addition of spaces, as the previous exaple shows).

Now, after the explanation, the problem is the following: after running the main class, which calls the method that contains the previous code, a runtime exceptions pops out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
    at main2.main(main2.java:75)
```

I don't understand why it is finding any of the lists as "empty". I have tried to solve it in too many ways, I hope a I gave a good explanation.

It may help as a clue that if I assign mdef to the lengthiest size instead of the shortest, that is :

```
int mdef = (def1.size() >= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size();
```

the error changes to:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 15
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
    at asmethods.lcc.turnIntoFlex(lcc.java:55)
    at asmethods.lcc.calLcc(lcc.java:99)
    at main2.main(main2.java:73)'
```

Where lcc is the class that contains the method turnIntoFlex that contains the piece of code I'm showing. The line 55 of "turnIntoFlex" corresponds to the first line of the loop, that is:

```
if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) { [...]
```

Comments: The values of defA1 and defA2 are the definitions, respectively. i.e. def1 and def2, initially, are lists in which each separate element is a word. I can't check if these lists are being populated by printing them because the indexoutofboundsexception pops at the very moment the loop starts. However, I do print the values of the sizes of mdef, def1.size() and def2.size(), and the values turn out to be 13, or 15, showing that no list is empty before the "for" loop starts.

The mdef++ was something I added recently, not to exactly to solve this specific problem, but the error has been popping since before I added the mdef++ part. As I explained, The intention is to increase mdef++ when the shortest list is extended (but only when the short list is extended) so we iterate through all the words of the short list, and not more.

Comment: Is your problem intended to add elements to `def2` or just replace them?

Comment: it would be better if u can tell us the line where you get the exception..

Comment: Yeah. Beautiful long explanation, but is it relevantly correct and the issue really severe? Provide accurate line numbers first, because as always, specificity in posing questions will do most of the work in resolving bugs.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @asvikki and clwhisk, but as I explained in the description, the line where I get the error is the corresponding piece of code: if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) { [...]

Comment: The problem is intended to add blank spaces to any of the two definitions @Christian.

Comment: Have you tried what Turix said? Print some index to check where you are getting an index higher than the expected.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is that when you increment `mdef` you do not check to see if it *now* exceeds the length of the *other* list.

For example, suppose `def1` had 3 words and `def2` had 4 words.  `mdef` would start at 3.  But then suppose you successively add two spaces to `def1` and increment `mdef` twice to be 5.  This now exceeds the length of `def2` and will then cause an index out of bounds exception in the `def2` `else` condition if you keep iterating up to 5.

---

Added later:

Another serious issue with your code (that I thought of later) is that when you add the space to a list (either `def1` or `def2`) this shifts the indices of all of the subsequent elements up by 1.  So, for example, if you add a space at spot 0 in `def1` when `i` is 0, then on the next pass through the loop, having incremented `i` to 1, you will look at the same word in `def1` that you looked at in the previous pass.  This is probably the source of some of your exceptions (as it would lead to a continual loop until you exceed the length of the other list:  problem #1 above).

---

To correct both of these issues, you would need to change your code to something like:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < def1.size()  &&  j < def2.size()) {
    if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i)) && !stopList.contains(def2.get(j)))
        def2.add(j++, " ");
    else if (stopList.contains(def2.get(j)) && !stopList.contains(def1.get(i)))
        def1.add(i++, " ");
    ++i;
    ++j;
}
```

Note that you don't ned `mdef` any more in this implementation.

Comment: That's a very good point @Turix thank you for your answer. BUT do you think this is the reason why it is reporting an empty list? (index 1 size 0). Could you suggest some code or briefly explain an algorithm that could solve that issue? Although I may already be thinking in a way right now, I would appreciate a different idea.  Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Also I would appreciate if anyone can explain me how to select an answer as solution here in StackOverflow.

Comment: @EduardoCasillasAllen This would definitely explain the second out of bounds exception you included above.  Probably not the first (the "empty" list) though.

Comment: You can select an answer as solution clicking in the "Check" on the left-top corner of this answer.

Comment: @EduardoCasillasAllen To correct the two issues I highlighted above you need to add more code related to when you insert spaces into a list.  I will take a stab at that in my answer...

Comment: I will try to give a further look to your code, don't give up!

Comment: Thank you @Turix I'll try to implement your idea in code and then I'll choose an answer. Very good idea thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I think I got it. I modified the code, but I hope you understand what I did:

```
static public void main(String[] argv) {
    String[] sList = "of a in to under".split(" ");
    String[] definition1 = "Free fall descent of a body subjected only to the action of gravity"
            .split(" ");
    String[] definition2 = "Free fall movement of a body in a gravitational field under the influence of gravity"
            .split(" ");
    List<String> def1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> def2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> stopList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String word : definition1) {
        def1.add(word);
    }
    for (String word : definition2) {
        def2.add(word);
    }
    for (String word : sList) {
        stopList.add(word);
    }

    int mdef = (def1.size() <= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size(); // Shortest
                                                                            // length

    for (int i = 0; i < mdef; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (!stopList.contains(def1.get(i)) && !stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {
            continue;
        }

        else if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i)) && stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {
            continue;
        }

        else if (!stopList.contains(def1.get(i)) && stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {
            def1.add(i, " ");
            mdef = (def1.size() <= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size(); // define mdef again
        }

        else if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i)) && !stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {
            def2.add(i, " ");
            mdef = (def1.size() <= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size(); // define mdef again
        }

    }

    for (String word : def1) {

        if (word.equals(" "))
            System.out.print("_ ");
        else
            System.out.print(word+" ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (String word : def2) {
        if (word.equals(" "))
            System.out.print("_ ");
        else
            System.out.print(word+" ");
    }           
}
```

Comment: I think that still has the second of the two issues that I described in my answer.

Comment: But it's not a problem, you have to compare the same value with other value (because is a different index), in order to do the problem correctly.

Comment: I got some very interesting values with the printing part, seems like it is approaching to a good solution. The exception still pops, but the sentences are printed before this happens (although some other spaces were added where they shouldn't be added) Some of the code you added is to improve the writing, thanks for that I did implement the same and then I saw your answer.

Comment: If you could put some "real " input example it would be easier to improve. Can you give the inputs as Strings? So I can debug my code better. I will try to help you tomorrow, see you!

Comment: Absolutely right Christian. The input I actually enter to test my program are the following strings.  String firstDefinition  = "caida libre descenso de un cuerpo sometido unicamente a la accion de la gravedad";
 String secondDefinition = "caida libre movimiento de un cuerpo en un campo gravitatorio bajo la influencia de la gravedad";

Comment: The stoplist is a String as well:   String STOPLIST = "a aqu\u00ED cuantos esta misma nosotras querer tales usted ac\u00E1 cada cu\u00E1n estar mismas nosotros qu\u00E9 tan ustedes ah\u00ED cierta cu\u00E1nto estas mismo nuestra quien tanta varias ajena ciertas cu\u00E1ntos este mismos nuestras quienes tantas varios ajenas cierto de estos mucha nuestro quienesquiera tanto vosotras ajeno ciertos dejar hacer muchas nuestros quienquiera tantos vosotros ajenos como del hasta much\u00EDsima nunca

Comment: [...]qui\u00E9n te vuestra al c\u00F3mo demasiada jam\u00E1s much\u00EDsimas os ser tener vuestras algo con demasiadas junto much\u00EDsimo otra si ti vuestro alguna conmigo demasiado juntos much\u00EDsimos otras siempre toda vuestros algunas consigo demasiados la mucho otro s\u00ED todas y alguno contigo dem\u00E1s las muchos otros s\u00EDn todo yo algunos cualquier el lo muy para Sr todos alg\u00FAn bajo cualquiera ella los nada parecer Sra tomar all\u00E1 cualquieras ellas mas ni poca Sres tuya all\u00ED cuan [...]

Comment: [...] ellos m\u00E1s ninguna pocas Sta tuyo aquel cuanta \u00E9l me ningunas poco suya t\u00FA aquella cuantas esa menos ninguno pocos suyas un aquellas cu\u00E1nta esas m\u00EDa ningunos por suyo una aquello cu\u00E1ntas ese mientras no porque suyos unas aquellos cuanto esos m\u00EDo nos que tal unos"; [...]

Comment: As you can see its a long stoplist. But there you have real inputs.

Comment: Ok I see. Can you add it to your post? So I dont make mistakes copying it. Also can you put the s
desired output? . Por cierto tambien hablo espanol. Debo ir a dormir nos vemos.

Answer (score -2):

Is this the exact code you're using? I just ran it and it worked fine, I used:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        String stoplist= "of a in to and under";
        String defA1 = "Free fall descent  of a body subjected only to            the   action of  gravity";
        String defA2 = "Free fall movement of a body in        a    gravitational field under  the influence of gravity";

        String[] sList = stoplist.split(" ");  //this is the stoplist
        String[] definition1 = defA1.split(" ");  //this is the array of words of the first definition
        String[] definition2 = defA2.split(" ");  //this is the array of words of the second definition
        List<String> def1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> def2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> stopList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String word : definition1) {
            def1.add(word); //I transform arrays into lists this way because I used to think that using .asList() was the problem.
        }
        for (String word : definition2) {
            def2.add(word);
        }
        for (String word : sList) {
            stopList.add(word);
        }

        int mdef = (def1.size() <= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size(); //here mdef will have the value of the lenght of the shortest definition, and we are going to use the value of mdef to iterate later on.

        for (int i = 0; i < mdef; i++) {
            if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) {  //here I check if the first word of the first definition is also found in the stoplist.
                if (!stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {  //If the word of def1 previously checked is in the stoplist, as well as the corresponding word in the second definition, then we won't add a " "(blank) space in the corresponding position of the second definition.
                    def2.add(i , " "); //here I add that blank space, only if the stoplist word in def1 corresponds to a non-stoplist word in def2. Again, we do this so the stoplist word in def1 corresponds to a blank space OR another stoplist word in def2.
                    if (mdef == def2.size())
                        mdef++; //In case the shortest definition is the definition to which we just added spaces, we increment mdef++, because that space added increases the length of the shortest definition, and to iterate in this recenlty extended definiton, we have to increment the index with which we iterate.
                }
            } else if (stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) { //this else if does the same than the previous one, but checks for the second definition instead of the first one. And adds blanks to def1 instead of def2 if necessary.
                if (!stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) {
                    def1.add(i , " ");
                    if (mdef == def1.size())
                        mdef++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (String word : def1) {
            System.out.print(word+",");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (String word : def2) {
            System.out.print(word+",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: True, but that's an issue with the algorithm, but there's no indexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Yes it is the exact code, then there must be something else making the exception pop. You know, this code is not in a main method, is in a method of a class of a package that is called in the main method. Maybe you may need more information.

Comment: Well, in fact, is not the EXACT same code, actually I have a much larger stoplist in spanish, the sentences are in spanish as well but the results should be the same with the stoplist and sentences I provided, trust me.